# If value in one div is higher than other

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a div if the value in one div is higher than an other. So far I have this:

```
<div class="limit">500</div>
<div class="leased">600</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

```js
$("#next").toggle($(".leased").text() > $(".limit").text());
```

So in effect if the value in the `.leased` div is higher than the value in the `.limit` div the `#next` div is hidden.

Currently I'm just seeing all divs display. I've done quite a bit of Googling, but no joy. It's probably too basic!

Comment: thats javascript, or jQuery, not php

Comment: `toggle` doesn't take a true or false as parameter to make it shown or hidden. wrap it in a normal `if - else` and then show or hide `'#next'`!

Comment: Is your requirement satisfy?

Comment: @Jeff that's not true, `toggle()` accepts a boolean just fine: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ooh, that's new.   Wait, added 1.3?  I'm old.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close, you just need to convert the values you're comparing to integers using `parseInt()`. You also need to reverse the comparison to hide `#next` when the `.leased` value is higher. Try this:

```js
$("#next").toggle(parseInt($(".leased").text(), 10) < parseInt($(".limit").text(), 10));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="limit">500</div>
<div class="leased">600</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for the code. Great suggestion

Answer (score 3):

A few things are incorrect in your code:

1. You need to convert the `text` values you get from both the `div` to numbers using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` whichever suits your needs. Without it, comparison will be string based and produce unexpected results.

So, I have converted both values to integers here, and I check if lease is greater than limit, `#next` element is hidden, otherwise `#next` is shown.

```
if( parseInt($(".leased").text()) > parseInt( $(".limit").text() ) )
{
  $("#next").hide();
} 
else
{
  $("#next").show();
}
```

As mentioned by other people, [`toggle()` does take a boolean variable](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display). So, your own code can be modified simply by adding `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to it:

```
$("#next").toggle(parseInt($(".leased").text(), 10) < parseInt($(".limit").text(), 10));
```

Comment: `toggle doesn't take a true or false as parameter to make it shown or hidden` yes it does: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display. You should also include the radix when using `parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not php code ,just jquery! your should write your condition first before function is run..

```
if($(".leased").text() > $(".limit").text()){
$("#next").toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look following snippet.

```js
//$("#next").toggle($(".leased").text() > $(".limit").text());
//alert($(".leased").text());
//alert($(".limit").text());

if($(".leased").text() > $(".limit").text()){
    $("#next").toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="limit">500</div>
<div class="leased">600</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```